# How do i connect a windows 7 machine to fedora?

Tags: fedora, raspberry-pi

Before I continue, you can move this question to answer section. I am not sure where its best suited.

I have just got this "TP-Link TL-SF1005D 5-Port 10/100Mbps Unmanaged Desktop Switch" network switch, I have a pi, a desktop running fedora and a windows 7 machine.

I was wondering how do I connect the 3 devices together so i can form a network.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the purpose of that experiment, you may only need Ethernet cables to connect the Pi, the Win7 and Fedora server together via your switch.

If you need to route the network traffic through Fedora server, you have to have two different network cards in it, one functioning as WAN, one as LAN. This is because your TP-Link is a "switch", not a router. So, it does not handle the network management, only packet switching. To see how the network configuration is done, read up on LHN (Linux Home Networking) site, which has a set of HOWTOs to do the network configuration. See the [DHCP guide](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch08_:_Configuring_the_DHCP_Server) for example.

If, however, you are more into file sharing, check out Samba (http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-a-linux-file-server-using-samba). 
Depending on your requirements, Pi can also either use Samba client to connect to the share, or NFS to connect to your Fedora server. LHN site has a guide for it as well.